# How can I use function arguments where variables exist with the same name?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

If I have a column in a `data.frame` that has the same name as one of the arguments to my function, the column name is used when trying to `mutate` or `filter`.

Is there a way to explicitly use the function parameter?

Reproducible example:

```r
my_function <- function(x) {
  my_tib <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y,
    1,  5,
    2,  10,
    3,  15
  )

  my_tib %>%
    mutate(z = x * y)
}

my_function(x=100)

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     5     5
#2     2    10    20
#3     3    15    45
```

Desired result:

```
my_function(x=100)

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     5    500
#2     2    10    1000
#3     3    15    1500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `{{` operator although avoiding the conflict in the first place seems a better way to avoid possible headaches.

```
library(dplyr)

my_function <- function(x) {
  my_tib <- tribble(
    ~x, ~y,
    1,  5,
    2,  10,
    3,  15
  )

  my_tib %>%
    mutate(z = {{x}} * y)
}

my_function(100)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5   500
2     2    10  1000
3     3    15  1500
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I didn't think to use NSE for this

Comment: If you don't want to use NSE, you can just force `mutate()` to use the env-variable `x` instead of the data-variable `x` with `!!`. E.g. `mutate(z = !!x * y)`

Answer (score 2):

In the currently accepted answer, it is suggested to use curly-curly to substitute the function argument.

```
my_tib <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1,  5,
  2,  10,
  3,  15
)

my_function_nse <- function(data, x) {
  data %>% mutate(z = {{ x }} * y)
}
```

This works well with literal numbers:

```
my_tib %>% my_function_nse(100)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5   500
#> 2     2    10  1000
#> 3     3    15  1500
```

However you'll get the same data-masking issue when you use variables:

```
x <- 100
my_tib %>% my_function_nse(x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     5
#> 2     2    10    20
#> 3     3    15    45
```

What's happening here is that the data variable `x` has precedence over the environment variable `x`. To work around this, the user needs to force the env-var `x` with the forcing operator `!!`:

```
my_tib %>% my_function_nse(!!x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5   500
#> 2     2    10  1000
#> 3     3    15  1500
```

You can also force inside the function:

```
my_function_se <- function(data, x) {
  data %>% mutate(z = !!x * y)
}
```

In this case, your function doesn't use NSE at all. It doesn't have the data masking problem:

```
my_tib %>% my_function_se(x)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5   500
#> 2     2    10  1000
#> 3     3    15  1500
```

Of course the flip side is that you cannot refer to data-variables at all:

```
my_tib %>% my_function_se(y + 10)
#> Error : object 'y' not found

my_tib %>% my_function_nse(y + 10)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5    75
#> 2     2    10   200
#> 3     3    15   375
```

Comment: Thanks, I also didn't realise that `!!` would evaluate the variable x. I guess it comes down to how I want to enter the parameters to my function whether I should use `!!x` or `!!enquo(x)` (or the newer `{{x}}`).

Comment: Exactly, it's a UI choice.